# Java Junit test HTTP POST request not working

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, spring-test

So I am trying to add integration test to my API, I tested all of the GET/POST/PUT.. methods via Postman and they all work, however I cannot get them to work on JUnit with mockito, any ideas?

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ResponseStatusControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private String content;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new NsaController())
                .build();

        try(FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("\\java\\resources\\post.json")) {
            content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void endpointTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/nsascholarship",content)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());}
}
```

The code should take the JSON data and post it to the H2 database, however depending on how I give the JSON object (in a string) I get:

Status expected:<200> but was:<400> (400 is when the provided data has nulls where there should be data)

My assumption is for some reason I am providing the JSON body incorrectly and the method is unable to add it to the database.

TLDR; Post requests works on Postman, does not work on Junit. I think its because I am not providing the JSON content correctly via the test method, any ideas?

Comment: In other words, the live code demonstrates that the test is broken.   So much for the testing strategy...

Comment: Would not agree. All of the functionalities are working as expected and this is my first time implementing integration tests onto a project. Postman is a UI so obviously it's a lot easier to use while setting up the tests with it.

Comment: Did you inspect `content` in a debugger to see that the JSON was read correctly? Does the console output show any error messages from the parsing/binding of the API call ("server" side)?

Comment: Check the content (body) of the response to see if there is anything useful in there to help you troubleshoot. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18336481/639520) for how to do that.

Comment: yes, the JSON string itself is read correctly and no there isin't any parsing/binding issues.

Comment: @E-Riz one thing is that if I do ".content(content)" instead of "post('url', content)" I receive a null pointer, which Is how I assume that the post requests get's sent with no body, thoughts?

Comment: @E-Riz apologies for the spam, but using the link you provided, the body is indeed empty in the request with the "post(..)" approach and the ".content(content)" is a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the overloaded method `post(String, Object...)` that you're calling doesn't do what you think it does. The secondary `Object` params are to populate the URL template that's passed in the first parameter. See [the JavaDoc for explanation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#post-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).
So you need *do* to call `content(String)` on the `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` that you get back from the `post()` method.

Now, in order to troubleshoot a problem like this I suggest structuring your test a little differently, to make it easier to debug.

For example:

```java
String content = "{}";
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request =
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/v1/something")
                                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(content);
MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request)
                        .andReturn();
                        // andExpect(status().isOk())
                        // andExpect(...)
                        // ;
```

I would start with that hard-coded JSON content (or something else hard-coded but simple) and use a debugger to check along the way that each local variable is what I expect it to be.

With that, you can inspect the `MvcResult` that you get back to help determine what's going wrong.

Once you have it working, you can remove the `andReturn()` if you want and uncomment the assertions (such as `andExpect(status().isOk())`) .

Comment: I've tried with .content(content), however with it I receive a nullPointerException, which is not something I get if I test with Postman. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the NPE coming from? How can you expect anyone to help you troubleshoot an exception without a stack trace?